# Invalid regular expression: Invalid group in node.js

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to map ELB load-balancer logs to have a common format like nginx and have this regex

```
const splitElbEntry = (elbLogEntry) => R.match(/(?P<date>[0-9-]+T[0-9:]+)\.\S+/)
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?P<date>[0-9-]+T[0-9:]+)\.\S+/: Invalid group
```

where as on https://regexr.com/3o06l it is finding the timestamp, although if I add a new group the regex fails.

What will be the correct javascript equivalent for https://regex101.com/r/JOlrxS/5

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: The selected flavor in regexr is PCRE and your end flavor is JS. JS doesn't support `(?P<name>...)` notation.

Comment: Correct is `/([0-9-]+T[0-9:]+)\.\S+/`, use a numbered capturing group.

Answer (score 3):

The selected flavor in regexr is PCRE and your end flavor is JS. JS doesn't support `(?P<name>...)` notation. However, `(?<name>...)` would be implemented in ECMAScript 2018 (currently supported by Google Chrome).

You can't, as of now, use a named capturing group that works among all major browsers. Deal with simple numbered capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

I got the required result using numbered capturing groups, thanks for the help.

https://regex101.com/r/JOlrxS/6

```
([0-9-]+T[0-9:]+)\.\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+):\d+\s+\S+:\d+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+\"\S+\s+\w+:\/\/([\w\-\.]*):\d+(\/\S*)\s+[^\"]+\"\s+\"([^\"]+)\"\s+\S+\s+\S+
```