# node uri regex not capturing capture groups

Tags: node.js, regex

I know there are a billion regex questions on stackoverflow, but I can't understand why my uri matcher isn't working in node.

I have the following:

```
var uri = "file:tmp.db?mode=ro"

function parseuri2db(uri){
    var regex = new RegExp("(?:file:)(.*)(?:\\?.*)");
    let dbname = uri.match(regex)
    return dbname
}
```

I'm trying to identify only the database name, which I expect to be:

1. After an uncaptured `file:` group
2. Before an optional `?` + parameters to end of string.

While I'm using:

```
var regex1 = new RegExp("(?:file:)(.*)(?:\\?.*)");
```

I thought the answer was actually more like:

```
var regex2 = new RegExp("(?:file:)(.*)(?:\\??.*)");
```

With a 0 or 1 `?` quantifier on the `\\?` literal.  But the latter fails.

Anyway, my result is:

```
console.log(parseuri2db(conf.db_in.filename))

[ 'file:tmp.db?mode=ro',
  'tmp.db',
  index: 0,
  input: 'file:tmp.db?mode=ro' ]
```

Which seems to be capturing the whole string in the first argument, rather than just the single capture group I asked for.

My questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong that I'm getting multiple captures?
2. How can I rephrase this to capture my capture groups with names?

[I expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex) something like the following to work for (2):

```
function parseuri2db(uri){
  // var regex = new RegExp("(?:file:)(.*)(?:\\?.*)");
  // let dbname = uri.match(regex)
  var regex = new RegExp("(?<protocol>file:)(?<fname>.*)(<params>\\?.*)");
  let [, protocol, fname, params] = uri.match(regex)
  return dbname
  }
  console.log(parseuri2db(conf.db_in.filename))
```

But:

```
  SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<protocol>file:)(?<fname>.*)(<params>\?.*)/: Invalid group
```

### Update 1

Answer to my first question is that I needed to not capture the `?` literal in the second capture group:

```
"(?:file:)([^?]*)(?:\\??.*)"
```

Comment: You are missing a `?` in the `params` group. It should be `(?<params>\\?.*)`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work though. Perhaps named groups [are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49864874/4934172)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular node regex library does not support groups.